# Change the scale of overlay video based on audio level

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm looking to adjust the scale of my image overlay based on the input audio's loudness.

As the volume rises, I want to make it larger, as it gets quieter, I want to make it smaller.

I can't figure out how to access any relevant audio information in video filters.

I'm open to multi-step solutions but the result needs to be in sync